# How can this awk command be simplified?

Tags: string, bash, parsing, awk

I'm trying to read a variable from a file that is NOT a bash script. The file contents are pretty much like this:

```
App(
    # Folder name of the application same as application id
    # Only file name appropriate characters, single "word" allowed
    # for appid
    appid="my_app",
    # name of the app
    name="Voltage Calculator",
    apptype=platform.EXTERNAL,
    # (entry point) of the application
    entry_point="my_app_main",
    stack_size=2 * 1024,
    # Application category
    category="Tools",
    requires=["gui"],
    app_icon="icons/my_app.png",
    app_icon_assets="icons",
    # Optional values
    app_version=(1, 0),
    # Short text description of the app, no links or markup/markdown
    # here.
    app_description="App does this cool thing",
    app_author="My name",
    app_weburl="https://github.com/myrepository/",
```

My solution thus far, to extract a variable value from this file is this:

```
filename=~/Programming/myfile.ext
awk -F'appid' '{print $2}' $filename | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs
```

The reason I stated emphatically that it wasn't a bash script is because I read many, many, many, SO answers similar to this where they tell you to "source" the file. Since this isn't a bash script, that doesn't seem logical.

My question is, can this be simplified with 'awk' so I'm not piping its' output three separate times? Or is this perfectly acceptable?

The 'xargs' is to eliminate the tons of white-space that seemed to surround the result.

Comment: please update the question to show the expected results for variables `appid`, `another` and `option`

Comment: Regarding "The 'xargs' is to eliminate the tons of white-space that seemed to surround the result." - then your real input file doesn't look "pretty much" enough like the file you showed us since running the command you provided, minus the pipe to xargs, against the file you provided would not result in tons of white-space being output and so you're unlikely to get the best solution for your real input file. Create and post a [mcve] that demonstrates your actual problem so we can help you with it.

Comment: You're getting answers that will fail when your string values contain `=` and `"` (e.g. try them with input like `appid="foo=bar"` or `appid="foo""quoted""bar"` or `appid="foo\"quoted\"bar"`) so make sure to include those and any other rainy-day cases in your example when you post it.

Comment: @markp-fuso I thought I did that in the OP, but I will try to update with some more examples.

Comment: @Ed Morton Those are extremely unlikely and not allowed characters in this case, I will try to reflect that in the post.

Comment: `grep -Po '^\s*appid="\K[^"]+'` ?

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you need, using any POSIX awk, but without more truly representative sample input and expected output it's just a partially tested guess:

```
$ awk '
    {
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|"?[[:space:]]*,?[[:space:]]*$/,"")
        sub(/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"?/,"=")
        tag = val = $0
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        sub(/[^=]+=/,"",val)
    }
    tag == "appid" {
        print val
    }
' file
myapp
```

Don't set `FS` to `=` and then try to use `$1` and/or `$2` as that'll make it harder to do this job robustly and handle input like:

```
appid="foo=bar"
```

Similarly for other characters. Instead use the approach I show above to first remove extraneous spaces and other chars from the start/end of the line and around the first `=` and then use `sub()`s to separate the string before the first `=` on each line (the tag/name) such as `appid` from the string after it (the value) such as `foo=bar`.

Comment: Definitely a robust answer. I will definitely add this to my toolbox!

Comment: This is also the only answer so far that has produced a result.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'thisthing (
# a comment
appid="myapp",
# comments
othervariable="something",
another=somethingelse,
option=["blah"],
)' |
```

---

```
mawk '$0 = $2' FS='^[ \t]*appid[ \t]?=[ \t]?"|"[^"]*$'
```

---

```
myapp
```

All other rows with double quotes (`"`) but without `appid=` in front would have its `$2` set to the right of end of row, i.e. `$2 == ""`, and thus wouldn't print since evaluating the empty string pattern always yields 0 (false).

An alternate approach is to use `RS` instead of `FS` :

*(which works for all except `gawk -P` or `gawk -c`, since those handle multi-char `RS` by only using the first char, whatever it is)*

```
gawk NF RS='^.*[ \t]*appid[ \t]?=[ \t]?"|".*$'
```

---

```
myapp
```

Comment: I haven't tried the gawk solution you provided yet, but the mawk one above did. I didn't even know mawk was a thing. Thanks.

Comment: either solution works on either `awk` (except the specified edge cases) i just wrote it like that to showcase the code is portable.

Answer (score 0):

Using custom field separator in awk you can simplify your awk commands into just a single one like this:

```bash
awk -F '="|",' '$1 == "appid" {print $2}' "$filename"

myapp
```

Comment: This produced a blank result.

Comment: It worked with the input data you had shown in question. Check for presence of dos line ending in your input